# PlayerPrefs addition and subtraction

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm Working on a Game in which the total money collected is shown on the menu screen. Now I have Used this code: `GUIManager.SetScore((PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Player Score")));` to Show the last game played's coins, but I don't know how to show the ***Total*** money collected ever since the start of the game. And I would also like to know how to subtract from the total money (for purchases)

Comment: Are you keeping track of the total money a player earns anywhere? If not, I would probably start with that...

Comment: No, How Do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a PlayerPref float by calling `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat`, so eg, when you want to set the "Player Score" within the playerPrefs to 10, you'd call `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", 10)`

In order to add or subtract, you could do something like this:

```
void AddScore(float score)
{
   if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Player Score"))
   {
       float oldScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Player Score");
       PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", oldScore  + score);
   }
   else PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", 0);
}
```

And similarly for Subtraction

```
void SubtractScore(float score)
{
   if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Player Score"))
   {
       float oldScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Player Score");
       if((oldScore - score) < 0)
           PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", 0);
       else
           PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", oldScore  - score);
   }
   else PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", 0);
}
```

Now, if you want to add another new PlayerPref, then all you do exactly the same as above, but just change "Player Score" to a name of your choosing (eg "Player Coins" or something along those lines)